# Can I host my console application in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I've read in some articles that we can create a console application in .NET & we can host that in IIS which makes our console application as web application. Is it a rumour or can we actually do that?
Also, please provide a working example or procedural steps for that, if we could do that?

Thanks

Comment: I got the info from [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)

Comment: Can you quote the part about console application hosting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596498/publishing-a-c-sharp-console-application-on-iis-server

Comment: @MatteoUmili I didnt get your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publishing a c# console application on IIS Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596498/publishing-a-c-sharp-console-application-on-iis-server)

Comment: @anvesh.veerelli Matteo means the link you gave us goes to a very large article, can you copy and paste the sentence that talks about console application hosting in to a comment so we can do a Find in the article and see which paragraph you are reading.

Comment: The link has these below lines,                                                             For example, you can host the ASP.NET runtime in a Windows form (check out  http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp for more detailed information on runtime hosting in Windows Forms apps).

Answer (score 1):

Console application cannot be run as web application in IIS by itself unless you have a web application calling your console application to trigger on it. of course your console application path must be accessible.

Configured framework, run time at ease.